# Cannot autowire entity argument with @ParamConverter declaration

Tags: php, symfony

I encountered an issue with @ParamConverter. Entities arguments are detected such as "service".

I think that multiples route arguments and @ParamConverter are responsables of this issue.

I have tried to deactivate `auto_convert` option in `sensio_framework_extra` without success.

```php
Cannot autowire argument $category of "App\Controller\Front\QuestionController::showRandomAction()": it references class "App\Entity\Category" but no such service exists.
```

#### sensio_framework_extra.yaml

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    router:
        annotations: false
    request:
        converters: true
        auto_convert: false
```

#### Controller

```php
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/{slug}/", name="app_front_question_show", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 * @ParamConverter(name="category", class="App\Entity\Category", options={"mapping": {"slug": "slug"}})
 * @ParamConverter(name="question", class="App\Entity\Question", options={"mapping": {"id": "id"}})
*/
public function showAction(
   Request $request,
   Category $category,
   Question $question,
   AnswerRepository $answerRepository,
   ReportQuestionManager $reportQuestionManager
) {
    // ...
}
```

Stack:

```
* Symfony 4.4
```

Comment: Your code seems good. Your problem is probably linked about multiples arguments and multiples @ParamConverter that you used. Could you try to use `exclude` option in `mapping` option to be more explicit.  [More detail](https://shortly.cc/ZwgKR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the response but Baptiste is right.

I managed to do what I wanted by correcting the ParamConverter annotations.

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/{slug}/", name="app_front_question_show", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 * @ParamConverter("category", class="App\Entity\Category", options={"mapping": {"slug": "slug"}})
 * @ParamConverter("question", class="App\Entity\Question", options={"mapping": {"id": "id"}})
*/
public function showAction(
   Request $request,
   Category $category,
   Question $question,
   AnswerRepository $answerRepository,
   ReportQuestionManager $reportQuestionManager
) {
    // ...
}
```

I should not put the "name=''"

The `auto_convert: false` is good and do what I want

I close the post.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It’s because You’re using param converters and you deactivate them with `auto_convert : false` .
You can see [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#usage)
“You can disable the auto-conversion of type-hinted method arguments feature by setting the auto_convert flag to false”

Comment: `auto_convert` allow to retrieve data from Doctrine implicitly without using @ParamConverter.